# How can I manually import a boot-image in MAAS?

Tags: maas

I've just started to try MAAS. The document suggests me to import a boot-image first. But after I clicked the 'import boot-image' button on MAAS webpage, and waited for a long long time, the image was still not ready.

Neither can I load the image, nor see the progress of importing.

My question is: is there a way to manually import an image and configure it in MAAS system? Or at least can I view the downloading progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1172773), the downloading progress feature was added since MAAS 1.7.0.

However, if you use Ubuntu Trusty, the current MAAS version is 1.5.x.
You may try to use the newer version MAAS of PPAs of [maas maintainers](https://launchpad.net/~maas-maintainers) .
For example, you may try [Experimental PPA](https://launchpad.net/~maas-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/experimental), [dailybuild PPA](https://launchpad.net/~maas-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/dailybuilds), or [Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~maas-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

If you have any problem to use PPAs, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. There has been such a long time that I didn't check my message box...